# How using the Excel macro VBA to create a new file where numbers as values from the sheet in the initial file?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 sheets A, B and C. A has hyperlinks to B and A has cells where formulas take values from sheet C. I want to create a new file where there are only 2 sheets A and B. As a result I am thinking that macro code should include code which tells that copy paste A (from initial file) to sheet A (in new file). Unfortunately I am new in VBA and cannot figure out which code to use. Could you help?

I used the following code, however as formulas depend on C I got errors.

```
Sub newfile()
    Sheets(Array("A", "B")).Select
    Sheets(Array("A", "B")).Copy


    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:XX.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: *"I got errors"* Which errors? • How can A and B work if they depend on a C that disappears? Please clarify if you expect them to copy values only (convert formulas into values) or if you expect to have a cross workbook referenece (A and B in the new workbook reference to the C in the old workbook).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I meant the errors in the new A sheet, because as formulas not anymore valid. No, I do not want a cross workbook reference. I only want that in new workbook there are only values from old workbook sheet A.

Comment: Then jamhedart posted the answer below. You need to copy the current workbook, convert all formulas into values and finally delete the sheets that you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your sheet B calculated values to actual values.
I think it's easy to save the current workbook with a new name, resave with the current name, open the new book, convert the values and then delete sheet C. I've included an error handler too:

```
Sub e()
  Dim wb As Workbook ' declare a variable for the workbook
  On Error GoTo ErrHandle ' add an error handling step
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' turn off save-over alerts
  ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "NewBook.xlsm" ' save current book with new name
  ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "CurrentWorkBookName.xlsm" ' resave current book to preserve name
  Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open("NewBook.xlsm") ' open the new book
  wb.Sheets("B").UsedRange.Value = wb.Sheets("B").UsedRange.Value ' convert B calc values to actual values
  wb.Sheets("C").Delete ' delete sheet C
  wb.Close True ' close the new book and save the changes
  ErrHandle:
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description 'display error if there was one
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True ' turn on alerts again
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I have an issue that initial file I use every day (to update information), so it is better not to change it. As a result I need a new workbook with only values from initial file. And i tried your code, however formulas exist in new file (so no paste as values)

Comment: It won't change the initial file. It saves it with a new name and then saves it instantly with the original name. The changes are only made to the new copy with the new name. I'm not sure why the values don't convert to values for you, it worked fine on my test book. Make sure your new and current workbook names are correct.

Comment: after I created a new workbook it is said "Application-defined or object-defined error". May be this error shows any reason why up to specific row I have numbers as values. Additionally I noticed that the sheet that should be deleted  is not deleted from the workbook (actually i have more sheets than 3 in the workbook).
Additionally why this code will not work: Sheets(Array("A", "B")).Select
    Sheets(Array("A", "B")).UsedRange.Value.Copy and then use ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs  ?